# Loop (while True:) directly taking first input as else statement, but working fine on subsequent attempts

Tags: python, loops

I am working on a project in which I'm trying to get response from the user from a displayed list of items, if the response of the user is in the range of the items (1-5) i want to confirm whether the choice of the user is correct or not by prompting a [Y/N] question.

- If the user picks 'Y' I want to move to next but of the code by
  breaking out of the loop.
- If the user chooses 'N', I want to again display the choice to choose
  from the list (1-6).
- If any invalid entry is made i want to display an error message.

But whenever I'm executing the code, no matter what I'm giving as input in the [Y/N] prompt I'm always getting *'Invalid' as the first response* and being redirected to choose again from [Y/N] {desired to be redirected}

But if then I choose Y or N, I'm getting the corresponding message printed.

**It's weird that the first input always go as invalid and the subsequent ones work alright.** [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIOBo.png)

**Console log**

[image: console log]

```
i=1
while i<6:
    numberlist= str(i) + ') '
    stitle= numberlist + '' + result_lists[i]['title']
    print (stitle)
    i+=1
print()


defrng=[1,2,3,4,5]
#taking and confirming user anime choice
while True:
    try:
        titlenumber = int(input('Enter number of the title you want to choose: '))
        if titlenumber in defrng:
            userchoice=titlenumber    
            print('The selected title is: ' + str(userchoice) + ') ' + str(result_lists[userchoice]['title']))
            rptchoice=print(input('Continue with this choice? [y/n]: '))
            print(rptchoice)

            rptchoice= input('[Y/N]')

            if rptchoice == 'Y':
                print('Yes')
                break

            elif rptchoice == 'N':
                print('No')
                continue

            else:
                print('Invalid')
                continue
            
        else:
            print('Invalid entry')
            continue

    except ValueError:
        continue
        
print('success, [the rest of the code]')
```

Comment: Did you mean: `rptchoice = input('Continue with this choice? [y/n]: ')`?

Comment: On the line where you have:
`rptchoice=print(input('Continue with this choice? [y/n]: '))`
Can you try removing the print()?

Comment: while i<6:  i is not defined and in 6th line u have empty print. fix it to provide u correct debug

Comment: Empty print is allowed. But indeed, this is not a reproducible example. Probably you are missing some initialisation lines at the start of the code.

Comment: removed the print(), still facing the same issue

Comment: Initalized i=1, so that it prints 5 items in list. Still doesnt solve the issue

Comment: i declared i as int, now result_lists is not defined, declare ur needed variables first

Comment: Also remove: `rptchoice= input('[Y/N]')`

Comment: Solved! I had improper print statement and 2 inputs statement storing data in the same variable that led it to asking twice before executing the if else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will make it easier for yourself if you have a separate function for getting a yes/no answer from the user (returning a boolean), per example below.

Note that I added the first two lines just to make it runnable, because the question did not contain runnable code.

```
i = 0
result_lists = [{'title': 'thing ' + str(i)} for i in range(6)]

while i<6:
    numberlist= str(i) + ') '
    stitle= numberlist + '' + result_lists[i]['title']
    print (stitle)
    i+=1
print()

def get_yes_or_no(prompt):    
    while True:
        answer = input(prompt).upper()
        if answer == 'Y':
            return True
        if answer == 'N':
            return False
        print('Invalid')        

defrng=[1,2,3,4,5]
#taking and confirming user anime choice
while True:
    try:
        titlenumber = int(input('Enter number of the title you want to choose: '))
        if titlenumber in defrng:
            userchoice=titlenumber
            print('The selected title is: ' + str(userchoice) + ') ' + str(result_lists[userchoice]['title']))
            if get_yes_or_no('Continue with this choice? [y/n]: '):
                print('Yes')
                break
            else:
                print('No')
                continue
        else:
            print('Invalid entry')
            continue

    except ValueError:
        continue
        
print('success, [the rest of the code]')
```

In fact most of the `continue` statements are unnecessary here and could be omitted (although the one in the `except` block would then need to be replaced by `pass`).

*(The code in `get_yes_or_no` could be written using `if ... elif ... else ...` if preferred - although not required here because the `return` statements mean that if the previous test(s) evaluated `True` then the subsequent blocks are not reached.)*